# how to display two models in one CGridView

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have two tables, `1. Students`  `2.SrkParents.`

relations in Students model is,

```
'srkParents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SrkParents', 'studentID'),
```

relations in SrkParents model is,

```
'student' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Students', 'studentID'),
```

view is,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'students-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array('studentID','status','del',

array('name'=>'SrkParents.fathers_name',
'value'=>'$data->Students->fathers_name',
'type'=>'raw'),
array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',),),));
```

I dont know where i did mistake.. I get the error as shown below,

```
Property "Students.Students" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified Answer: Just change the relation has_one from has_many

```
'srkParents' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SrkParents', 'studentID'),
```

Comment: Thnx Saxena.. i tried those, but im getting the same error.. Am i need to do any changes in models criteria??

Comment: @sher yes...If you didnt added criteria then add this also in your models.: `$criteria->compare('srkParents',$this->srkParents,true);`

Comment: i have the default criteria, should i still need to add or wat?

Comment: yes in the default criteria add those lines like this: `public function search()
 { $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
           //Old Criteria//
          $criteria->compare('srkParents',$this->srkParents,true);`

Comment: i have tried, but still having the same error. Also i have a doubt, is that possible to add a model in criteria.. coz, SrkParents is one of my model.

Comment: @sher wait i didnt see the name property you have used. `'name' => 'SrkParents.fathers_name'` is wrong. Just change the name to `header' to check the value.

Comment: No, same error, i think cgridview didn't get the value of other model. OR maybe the relations error

Comment: @sher there is cross linking of your model.try to remove the relation of srkparent model.there is no need to add that relation as the relation is already set in the student model.You have set this relation.If am not clear please do mention.`'srkParents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SrkParents', 'studentID'),`
That means Students has many srkparents using studentid as foreignkey which match id of students

Comment: @ SAXENA, thanx bro, i have found the error, which is from the relations. I change it to HAS_ONE, and working fine.

Comment: @sher Plz tick as accepted answer to my edited suggestion.so i can help you more or as well as others also.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation `srkParents` is a `HAS_MANY` relation. Thus `$data->srkParents` is an **array** of `SrkParents` and not an object. Which makes sense, because your students have several parents.

I don't know enough about your model attributes, so i can only guess: One way to solve this would be to add a `get`er to your `Students` model which loops over `$this->srkParents` to find the father object and return the name from there:

```
public function getFatherName()
{
    foreach($this->srkParents as $parent)
        if($parent->sex=='m' /* just guessing */)
            return $parent->name;
}
```

Then you could use `$data->fatherName` in your grid view.

Comment: I have the foreign key in SrkParents detail for studentID, which means the relations is HAS_ONE, right?? I have changed it to HAS_ONE and working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation name is student and this is case sensetive.

Try to change `$data->Students->fathers_name` to `$data->student->fathers_name`.

Property `Students.Students` is not defined.

> What am I doing wrong?

- you trying to get field `Students` from model `Students` which is not defined.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i made mistake in relations. and now solved